# MFC CListCtrl::SetItemText() not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am a beginner in building MFC application. I've just started using list controls (in report view) and I am facing some problems while updating the list. I have three buttons for add, update and delete. Everything works well except the update. Here's the code.

```
void CAddDetailsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX); 
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_DEPARTMENT, departmentControl);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_NAME, m_name);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_ID, m_id);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_AGE_BUDDY, m_ageVariable);
    DDX_CBString(pDX, IDC_DEPARTMENT, m_department);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_listControl);
}

BOOL CAddDetailsDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here 
    ageSpin=reinterpret_cast<CSpinButtonCtrl*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_AGE_SPIN));   
    ageBuddy=reinterpret_cast<CEdit*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_AGE_BUDDY));   
    ageSpin->SetBuddy((ageBuddy));
    ageSpin->SetRange32(18,60);     
    departmentControl.AddString("Human Resource");
    departmentControl.AddString("Manager");
    departmentControl.AddString("Administrator");
    departmentControl.AddString("Desktop Engineer");

    m_listControl.InsertColumn(0,"ID",0,100);
    m_listControl.InsertColumn(1,"Name",0,100);
    m_listControl.InsertColumn(2,"Age",0,60);
    m_listControl.InsertColumn(3,"Department",0,100);       
    m_listControl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT );

    m_ageVariable="18";
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
    // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
void CAddDetailsDlg::OnBnClickedEdit()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here    
    UpdateData();
    if((m_id=="")||(m_name=="")||(m_department=="")||(m_ageVariable==""))
    {
        MessageBox("Please choose an item to edit","Error");
    }
    else
    {           
            int index=m_listControl.GetSelectionMark();
            m_listControl.SetItemText(index,0,m_id);
            m_listControl.SetItemText(index,1,m_name);
            m_listControl.SetItemText(index,2,m_ageVariable);
            m_listControl.SetItemText(index,3,m_department);            
            MessageBox("Successfully Updated","Info");       
    }       
}
void CAddDetailsDlg::OnBnClickedNewButton()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here    
    UpdateData();
    if((m_id=="")||(m_name=="")||(m_department=="")||(m_ageVariable==""))
    {
        MessageBox("Please fill in all the details","Error");
    }
    else
    {       
        int count=m_listControl.GetItemCount();
        count=m_listControl.InsertItem(count,m_id);
        m_listControl.SetItemText(count,1,m_name);
        m_listControl.SetItemText(count,2,m_ageVariable);
        m_listControl.SetItemText(count,3,m_department);        
    }
}
```

**Note:-**

The update function works fine if I update only the *ID*. If I try to update all/ many fileds, only the *ID* gets updated and nothing else. BTW, age is a spinControl, department is a comboBox and the other two are editBox.

**Edit:-**

I found that both, the value of variable `m_name` and the editBox value changes to the older values after the line `m_listControl.SetItemText(index,0,m_id);`. Its the same case with `m_age` and `m_department`.
If I comment the line `m_listControl.SetItemText(index,0,m_id);`, I can update everything at a time except the *ID*.

I am able to update everything by storing `m_name`, `m_age` and `m_department` in a local variable just before the line `m_listControl.SetItemText(index,0,m_id);` and using those variables in `SetItemText()`. But as I'm learning, I wanna know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Did you debug it ? What's the value of m`index`right after `int index=m_listControl.GetSelectionMark()`?

Comment: And please show the two versions of the code you describe under "Note". Generally when asking questions here, dont't describe your code, show it.

Comment: @Micheal walz, those are the two cases the user would do in UI and are not any separate versions of my code. And while debugging, 'm_name' value was the right value. But after the line 'm_listControl.SetItemText(index,0,m_id);' , m_name takes the old value. I have no clue.

Comment: Please explain that by editing your question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, Sorry. my bad. I updated the question now.

Comment: @HariRam, how you are getting new values of `m_name`, `m_age`, `m_department`, using editbox or something else??

Comment: @Himanshu, I'm using editBox. And I have associated a value variable to each of them.

Comment: How you are creating associated variable of editbox? may be you have given wrong Id. I tried making CString variable like `DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT, m_name);` and with `UpdateData();` it is working fine.

Comment: @Himanshu, that's exactly how I am doing. See my Edit in the question for more info.

Comment: Your `Edit:-` makes no sense. The value of the variable bound to a control by `DDX_Text()` can only change (to the text entered in that control) when you call `UpdateData(TRUE);` (`TRUE` it the default parameter). Please show the declaration of your variables, your `DoDataExchange()` function and the `BN_CLICK` handler.

Comment: As you have mentioned in edit that value is changing to old after some line, their you can use `Update(FALSE);` otherwise take separate CString variable and use `GetWindowText()` to get editbox value.

Comment: This question cannot be answered. We have no idea, what `m_listControl` is, or any of the other variables you are using. You provide information that looks a lot like someone doesn't know how to use a debugger. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise this question gets closed, as it is not useful to future visitors.

Comment: @IInspectable, So here's the code. See my edit

Comment: We still can't see, what type `m_listControl` or the other variables have.

Comment: @IInspectable, can't you read the title? And you mean m_id=="" is not enough to find its type?

Comment: @HariRam: You aren't here, because you have all the answers. You are here, because you are wrong. From experience, I don't trust anything but code. You may think that you are using a `CListCtrl`, but aren't. This wouldn't be the first time this happened. As for the `m_id==""`, that's not nearly enough information to deduce its type. It could be an integer (that's erroneously compared against a pointer), a custom type with overloaded `operator==`, a `std::string`, `CString`, `CStringA`, `CStringW`, or any number of other string implementation.

Answer (score 2):

i think you forget to add **UpdateData()** before your code which is under Update_Bn_Click because at my side i use your code with updatedata() and its working fine.

```
UpdateData();
int index=m_List.GetSelectionMark();
m_List.SetItemText(index,0,m_id);
m_List.SetItemText(index,1,m_Name);
m_List.SetItemText(index,2,m_Age);
m_List.SetItemText(index,3,m_DepartMent);
```

Comment: I've already tried this . Nothing helped. Somehow, the value of the variable and the value in the editBox both changes to the older one (even if I don't use UpdateData()). I think the problem is with the way I update.

Answer (score 1):

Try pumping some messages after updating the items.

```
while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: Throwing in random code until things appear to work is not a viable solution strategy. If you cannot explain, why this works, it doesn't.

Comment: So, there are 100 MFC developers still contributing with their expertise.  This is not the first time I get a downvote from you MF guys. My work here is done. 99 left. #DarwinAwards

Comment: Stackoverflow is not about quantity. It's about quality.

Comment: Three answers are something everyone can handle. It's better to provide hunches than nothing -- especially when it comes to rather diffuse problems. Btw.: We still wait for your quality answer...

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your sorting.
In your designer:
Properties>Behaviour>Sort set to None.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Item into 0 colomn index first.

**listcontrol->InsertItem(0,_T("text"));**

then, you can set text to the subItem;

**listctrol->SetItemText(0,1,_T(subText)):**

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure the Owner Data property of the control is set to FALSE.

Maybe try `m_List.Update(index)` after the last `SetItemText()`.

I must admit that everywhere I need updated list elements, I use an Owner Data `CListCtrl` because I think its faster in case of a big number of items and easier to handle in the long term.

Comment: What is the *"Owner Data property of the control"*? `CListCtrl::Update` is used only, when an application needs to force a redraw immediately. Adding items invalidates the control automatically, so there's no need to force a redraw. Proposing to use a virtual list control does not address the question at all.

Comment: Go to design view, click on the ListCtrl, and look at the controls properties. There you find "Owner Data" somewhere. CListCtrl::Update was just a hunch. I wan't proposing, just humbly mentioning that I have never tried to update a non owner data CLIstCtrl, so people don't nail me to the cross, if it doesn't work -- obviously in vain...

Comment: Yes it doesn't work. But it doesn't mean to down-vote it.

Comment: @Hari: What's the Visual Studio version you are using?

Comment: To make sure its not an updating issue, can you call GetSubItemRect() and then InvalidateRect() after SetItemText()?

Comment: Regarding your latest update: I suppose your member variables are of type CString. Is it possible that you messed these up with GetBuffer() somewhere without using ReleaseBuffer() finally? This is my favorite way to make CStrings behave funny.